Creating manage package Development org from Environment Hub
I am trying to create a Development org from a PBO org which has same namespace as packaging org. When I create a new dev org from the Environment Hub, the org created doesn't have the managed package prefix. I previously read or heard that development orgs are deprecated from the Dev Hub, but I couldn't find any documentation to confirm this. Is using Scratch orgs the only way to develop managed packages now?
I have added a namespace prefix using the Namespace Registry in the PBO org.
The steps I am currently following are:

Creating a Dev org from the Environment Hub.
Pushing package code to the new Dev org using Sfdx, but the deployment fails due to a namespace prefix error.

Do I need to configure any additional settings in the Environment Hub, or are managed package development orgs deprecated?
Thanks.

If you are developing a 2GP, while you do need an org on which the namespace prefix is registered, and you need to use you PBO as the dev hub, you should do all development for the package on scratch orgs, leaving the namespace org and your PBO clean.

I am starting work on an existing project that is created using 1gp packaging. So I can't migrate the existing package to 2gp now. I have worked 4-5 years ago on dev orgs which had same namespace of packaging package org for development. If it is not possible i think scratch org is only possiblity

1GP to 2GP migration is available as a preview (you cannot yet use the migrated package in production) and is on its way. You might consider waiting before moving to 2GP for this package. As to 2GP development, the best practice and expected process is to use scratch orgs. You will find lots of documentation about it if you search.

Thanks i will use scratch orgs.
